# jQuery use 'for' to duplicate div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create a number of divs so they fill a current window size. So far i have got it to make it once, but cant get this to repeat. I am putting them inside another div, so when the containing div reaches the height of the window it stops making them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(),
        divHeight = $('div.container').height(),
        html = $('<div class="line"></div>');

    for (i = 1, l = 10; i < l; i++) {
        $('div.container').append(html); }
```

How do substitute the i and l for the variables winHeight and divHeight? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that all lines have the same height (let me know), you could this :

```
var html, winHeight, lineHeight, howManyLines;
html = '<div class="line"></div>';
winHeight = $(window).height();
// appends one line in order to retrieve its actual height
lineHeight = $(html).appendTo('div.container').height();
// calculates the required number of lines to fill the window
howManyLines = Math.floor(winHeight / lineHeight);
// appends missing lines
$('div.container').append(
    new Array(howManyLines).join(html)
);
```

Comment: +1 - I'll upvote that even if I don't really like appending strings, but the array.join method is always cool

Comment: You're not actually appending strings; jQuery parses the HTML string into DOM elements to append.

Comment: @Blazemonger - of course it does, I just prefer creating the elements myself, being a control freak.

Comment: Thank you i will implement this! i have added '*12' to the variable howManyLines as there are 12 consecutive divs per line, and changed lineHeight to take the outerHeight due to a margin and this works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 5):

don't create `html` as a jQuery object, just create the html template

```
html = '<div class="line"></div>';
```

other wise it is like you are trying to append the same element in the loop, another solution is to use `clone()`

```
html = $('<div class="line"></div>');
```

then

```
$('div.container').append(html.clone());
```